# Why am I getting an "array to string conversion" error in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently having a problem with this error:

> array to string conversion

Here's the code:

controller:

```
function get_tariff()
{      
   $this->load->model('model_tariff');
   $data['destination']=$this->input->post('dest',true);
   $data['lines']=$this->input->post('lines',true);
   $data['weight']=$this->input->post('weight',true);
   $data['priceperkg']=$this->model_tariff->get_tariff();
   $data['pricetotal']=$data['priceperkg']* $data['weight'];
   $this->load->view('tariff_result',$data);
}
```

model:

```
function get_tariff()
{        
   $destination=$this->input->post('dest');
   $lines=$this->input->post('lines');
   $weightt=$this->input->post('weight');
   $this->db->select('price');
   $this->db->from('view_tariff');
   $this->db->where('city_name',$destination);
   $this->db->where('lines',$lines);
   $price=$this->db->get();
   return $price->result();    
}
```

view:

```
Price per kg <?php echo $priceperkg?>;
Bayar total <?php echo $pricetotall?>;
```

Comment: On which line you getting this error ?

Comment: Where is the line number of Error?

Comment: this line $data['pricetotal']=$data['priceperkg']* $data['weight'];

Comment: Add `var_dump($data['priceperkg'])` after the line you used `get_tariff` , it's probably is returned in an array format, you might need to use something like `$data['priceperkg']=$data['priceperkg'][0]` to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CodeIgniter database method `result()` returns an array of objects, not a string literal (price). You need to do some further transformations. For example, if you are expecting a single row, then try `row()` which returns a single object. In turn, you can then reference the property `price`:

```
return $price->row()->price;
```

Or, you can treat this several other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Read [CodeIgniter Active Result function](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

This function returns the `query result` as an **array of objects**, or **an empty array** on failure. Typically you'll use this in a http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```

The above function is an alias of **result_object()**.

If you run queries that might not produce a result, you are encouraged to test the result first:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->title;
      echo $row->name;
      echo $row->body;
   }
}
```